# App Service: Not able to read connection string setting from App settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, connection-string, asp.net-core-3.1

**What I am trying to achieve**

Hello, I have dotnetcore web Api which is running in Azure App Service server farm. I am trying to read the connection string from app service configuration app settings.

**What I have tried so far**

- Runtime version: netcoreapp3.1 version-2.31.0.1
- Hosting environment: Azure App Service

Below is how I am trying to read the connection string settings

```
var configValue = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PNLDBConnectionString"] ?? String.Empty).ToString();
```

I have added the connection string in app service configuration section as below

[image]

As well have added a app settings key as below

[image]

But in either way, if I am removing the connection string key from `app.config` and deploying; then while trying to run any API endpoint throws below error which essentially means the it's not able to read the said connection string property

[image]

Any idea, what I could be missing here? Please suggest.

**EDIT:**

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key ="Encrypted" value="true"/>
    <add key ="PNLDBConnectionString" value="connection string value"/>

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please share your appsettings.json file ?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I have edited the post and shared app.config file content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Kudu portal, under environment variables I could see the settings as

```
PNLDBConnectionString = xxxxxxxxxx
APPSETTING_PNLDBConnectionString = xxxxxxxxx
```

Using, `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_PNLDBConnectionString")` did the trick actually. Had to modify the code line a bit like

```
var configValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PNLDBConnectionString"] 
                 ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_PNLDBConnectionString")
                 ?? String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

- After Adding New ConnectionString in Azure Portal => Configuration =>  Application settings
  Add Connection string in  **appsettings.json** file

  ```
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=SQLAzure; Database=PNLDB; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  ```

In **Startup.cs**,
Setup configuration settings to overwrite the environmental variables with appsettings.json.

```cs
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public Startup()
{
    Configuration = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();    
}
```

Configure the DB in  `Startup`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ProjectContext>(options =>
        {
            var connString = Configuration.Get("PNLDBConnectionString");
            options.UseSqlServer(connString);
        });
}
```

- Check the Connection string in KUDU (Control Manager)

**Update**

```cs
var connection = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["PNLDBConnectionString”].ConnectionString;
```

Your assembly also needs a reference to System.Configuration.

- **I have found that you added  value in connection string section and using app settings in code.**
- You need to add value in App settings in portal

Comment: Thanks Harsitha for suggestions but there is nothing in my appsetting.json, rather the connection string is present in app.config file and that's the sole reason using `ConfigurationManager` class as in my posted question. Will that not work with app service? Or does it work only with appsetting.json. AFAIK, it really doesn't matter which config file I am using.

Comment: Moreover, I am not using EntityFramework at all. Rather using plain ADO.NET .. JFYI. Anyways that really doesn't makes any difference

Comment: Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core3x#connect-to-the-app-configuration-store

Comment: Harsitha, AppConfiguration is different, that's for centralized store for all app configurations. I don't need that. document link you posted  has nothing to do with this issue seems. Please check again

Comment: And also please check your connection string once, if it has any typo errors. Extra spaces or might have missed any spaces between.

Comment: Please check for update in the posted answer.

Comment: @Rahul - Any update regarding the issue ?

Comment: Hello Harshitha, it has been resolved now and I posted that as an answer here if in case it helps anyone in future. Appreciate a lot for your help, suggestions and following up on this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 6:

After you've added the ConnectionString in appSettings for local debugging (like in HarshithaVeeramalla-MT's answer), add this in Program.cs:

```cs
var configValue = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PNLDBConnectionString")
```

`GetConnectionString` comes from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, which should be always available for ASP.NET Core apps.